# Why does $.contains() return false?

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm trying to use $.contains() function, but I'm getting false everytime:

```
$.contains(openedParent, event.target); //evaluates to false
$.contains(event.target, event.target); //evaluates to false
```

As far as I know event.target is DOM element.

Here is the full code in JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xQyAm/

I would be grateful if someone could tell how to fix this. Thanks !

Comment: What is `openedParent`? Please include a **complete** example in the post.

Comment: `.contains()` only works for descendants. a dom node cannot be its own descendant, and therefore cannot .contains() itself.

Comment: I was trying to think of a logical test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ReferenceError: event is not defined @ http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:44

You forgot to add `event` as the first argument of the callback function.

Additionally, `$.contains()` expect DOM elements for both arguments - but you are passing a jQuery object as the first argument. Changing it like this fixes the whole issue:

```
$("#info").text("box1 contains box2 ? " + $.contains(openedParent[0], event.target));
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xQyAm/2/

Comment: So... too localized/RTFD problem?